# Material banner with stack not found

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, dart-null-safety

Today upgrade my flutter sdk for 2.8 and my widget break

Flutter sdk 2.5: The material bannner overleap my UI
[My UI in Flutter sdk 2.5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UlG93.jpg)

Flutter sdk 2.8: Material banner displace my UI
[My UI in flutter sdk 2.8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/apttA.jpg)

**Flutter doctor**

Running flutter doctor...
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):

1. [✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.8.0, on Linux Mint 20.2
   5.4.0-89-generic, locale es_PY.UTF-8)
2. [✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0-rc4)
3. [✓] Chrome - develop for the web
4. [✓] Android Studio (version 4.2)
5. [✓] VS Code (version 1.62.3)
6. [✓] Connected device (2 available)

**No issues found!**

**Example Code**

[Code in gist](https://gist.github.com/valdeortiz/e110ee89b6e04aeaa7cddd4995a16093)

OBS: sorry for my code

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Try to give an `elevation` to the banner. According to a change made in September 2021

```
/// If this property is null, then [MaterialBannerThemeData.elevation] of
   /// [ThemeData.bannerTheme] is used, if that is also null, the default value is 0.
/// If the elevation is 0, the [Scaffold]'s body will be pushed down by the
/// MaterialBanner when used with [ScaffoldMessenger].
```

The change is [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/commit/0082ff973eade4f090c0fd77310622b20817634a#diff-55af58e0524fb7e52f6cf9187ae243f27f5d56cdad8e7a04e5ded04aa568875a).